# Jquery select statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-selectors

If I have a html structure like this

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
etc...
```

Where the table tags just repeat. How would could I write a select statement that would get the third td tag from every table tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(3)')
```

Here is a [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eee9N/)

Comment: what about `$('table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3)')`?

Comment: Sure you could do that - `>` is a more specific case where it looks for specifically the child nodes (and not the grand children nodes). If that is the structure for all the tables consistently, then your case would work.

Answer (score 1):

just use [nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

```
$('td:nth-child(3)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: $("td:nth-child(2)").append(" - 2nd!");

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use:

```
$('table tbody tr td:last-child')
```

wich would work in css3, too:

```
table tbody tr td:last-child{
    background:red;
}
```